# Selecting first element verifying a condiction using xPath in libxml

Tags: c, xpath, libxml2

In libxml, I try to select the first element to verify a condition using xpath. If I understood correctly, "//div[contains(@id,'art')][1]" in xpath would give just one element, though I get more than one of them. I use the function getnodeset in the libxml tutorial (see [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/apd.html)). Here is the code :

```
xmlXPathObjectPtr result=getnodeset(def,(xmlChar*) "//div[contains(@id,'art')][1]"); // where def is a htmlDocPtr
xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
if(result)
{
nodeset=result->nodesetval;

if(nodeset->nodeNr>1)
    fprintf(stderr,"%i first div with id attribute *art* : %s\n",nodeset->nodeNr,nomDef);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
"//div[contains(@id,'art')][1]"
```

you want

```
"(//div[contains(@id,'art')])[1]"
```

The reason has to do with binding precedence. As you probably know, `[1]` is shorthand for `[position() = 1]`. In the variant that you were trying to use, this means "when the current node (the `div` element) is the first child of its parent". Clearly, there could be many such divs that are each the first child of their respective parent.

When you put parentheses around the expression `//div[predicate]` and append `[1]` to that, then you're asking the question you intended to ask: what is the first node in the nodeset selected by `//div[predicate]`?